# Don't understand why the navigation drawer icon shows up twice

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm not sure why my code causes the icon to show up twice in my application. Could someone take a look and tell me which line is doing it and perhaps how to fix it? I'm still kind of new to this sort of thing when it comes to android.

[image]

[image: http://imgur.com/npwY74r&zuxq11i#1]

Code:

```
info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get list items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

    // 2. App Icon 
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.raw.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            );

    // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    // 2.3 enable and show "up" arrow
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
     actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
    // then it has handled the app icon touch event

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What happens if instead of `R.raw.ic_drawer` you move the `ic_drawer` file to the `drawable` folder and access it via `R.drawable.ic_drawer`?

Comment: nope, no change haha. I copied the ic_drawer to one of the drawables and deleted the raw folder. Nothing changed

Comment: That was what I saw odd at first glance. I'd try it out by passing `R.drawable.ic_launcher` since that's usually a nice image to work with. Also, test on other devices/emulators to make sure it's a widespread issue.

Comment: oh i figured it out haha. See I was looking at this guide: http://hmkcode.com/android-creating-a-navigation-drawer/ and I didnt have the shadow icon in the bundle or that line of code. So everything got messed up. Thanks for helping though! really appreciate it!

Comment: That makes sense. You should post it as an answer, people are most likely going to, at some point, forget that NavDrawer icons should have an accompanying shadow image.

Answer (score 0):

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get list items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

    // 2. App Icon 
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            );

    // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    // 2.3 enable and show "up" arrow
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

    // just styling option
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START); 
    //this is the line of code i needed. and also download the icon package for the shadow

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
     actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns true
    // then it has handled the app icon touch event

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

    }
}
```

}